# How to conditionally render extra form options on checking dynamically generated check boxes in React?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, conditional-statements, rendering

can anyone help, i'm trying this in React but i'm really stuck.

I have 3 checkboxes on a child component that i have rendered dynamically using an array of options in state (in the parent component):

What i need to be able to do is, as per the below image: click on each checkbox and get further options.

https://discourse-user-assets.s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/original/3X/d/3/d385407399b0fa130741e653c9650ff9953282df.png

The checked options and the sub options (not just dropdowns, the third checkbox has input fields) all need to be available in state so i can collect them up and post them to a database

What i have so far is the below:

Array of options in state:

```
sowType: [
        "ProductSow",
        "Teradata Customer SOW",
        "Custom Professional Services SOW"
      ]
```

Final rendered checkboxes:

https://discourse-user-assets.s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/original/3X/4/5/45702836b84abe764917f4bdf5172258f4d3e39c.png

My problem is, i don't know what to do next. I have dynamically rendered the initial 3 check boxes but i don't know how to add the conditional rendering to get the sub boxes to appear on clicking the check boxes) and add the info selected from them to state.

i.e. can i only add the conditional rendering on checkboxes that have NOT been dynamically rendered from map or is there a way to do it, in which case how is it done?

My code so far is as below, it may not be the best setup for what i am trying to do:

Can anyone help??

This is the reference to the component in the parent with the props passed down:

```
<SowType
            title={"SOW Type"}
            setName={"SOW Type"}
            subtitle={"What type of SOW do you want to generate?"}
            type={"checkbox"}
            controlFunc={this.handleSOWTypeCheckbox}
            options={this.state.sowType}
            selectedOptions={this.state.sowTypeSelectedOption}
          />
```

This is the child component dynamically rendering the array of items from state:

```
    class SOWType extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor={this.props.name} className="form-label">
          {this.props.title}
          <h6>{this.props.subtitle}</h6>
        </label>
        <div className="checkbox-group">
          {this.props.options.map(option => {
            return (
              <label key={option}>
                <input
                  className="form-checkbox"
                  name={this.props.setName}
                  onChange={this.props.controlFunc}
                  value={option}
                  checked={this.props.selectedOptions.indexOf(option) > -1}
                  type={this.props.type}
                />
                {option}
              </label>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the method i am currently using in the parent when a checkbox is clicked in the child component (this basically takes the selected option from the array in state and puts the checked options into another array in state called 'sowTypeSelectedOption: [ ]',

```
handleSOWTypeCheckbox(e) {
    const newSelection = e.target.value;
    let newSelectionArray;

    if (this.state.sowTypeSelectedOption.indexOf(newSelection) > -1) {
      newSelectionArray = this.state.sowTypeSelectedOption.filter(
        item => item !== newSelection
      );
    } else {
      newSelectionArray = [...this.state.sowTypeSelectedOption, newSelection];
    }
    this.setState(
      {
        sowTypeSelectedOption: newSelectionArray
      } /*() =>
      console.log("sow Type Selection: ", this.state.sowTypeSelectedOption) */
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi, sandbox here if that helps, would be grateful if someone could take a look: https://codesandbox.io/s/rlmv6ojjyn

Comment: - For reference, the form container is the file called:
PdfGenFormContainer.js

- The relevant child component is called: SOWType.js

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, you want the additional sub menu to show once the checkbox is selected, then you can use conditional rendering. Just show/hide the menu on select or deselect of checkbox like so.

```
{ this.props.selectedOptions.indexOf(option) > -1 ? (
  <h5>submenu options component renders here</h5>
  ) : " "
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me, I can’t get to my computer at the moment but I will check as soon as I can. That looks like it could work, one thing though, would this display the exact same div on the checking of any of the checkboxes, I need a different div to appear with different options extending from each checkbox, how would I do that, would that be an if/else statement rather than a ternary operator or would there be more to it than that?

Comment: Also, would it be better to have some kind of checked true/false condition held in state? Additionally, I would need a way to record the the additional selected options in state as they all need to be included in a form submission, so how would I put all that together?

Comment: Oh you definitely should be able to do it. Make an object that has component listed for that particular option like so                                         
    `componentList = {
    ProductSow: "component for productSow",
    "Teradata Customer SOW": "component for 2nd option",
    "Custom Professional Services SOW": "component for 3rd option"
  };`
and then refer to it like so in your conditional rendering:
`<h5>{this.componentList[option]}</h5>
                ) : (
                  " "
                )}`

Comment: Ternary operator is essentially if/else statement but just compact. You can use that if it makes more sense to you or its more readable. I just like to write less code. There are probably hundred ways to achieve what you want. Once you have components rendering, it shouldn't be too hard to get the data and make it into one object later in the parent component. Let me know if this works.

Comment: great thanks, i'll give your suggestions a try and see how i get on

Comment: Sorry, just one thing, do you mean put the componentList, (as per your above answer) into state?

Comment: No it can just be an object in the current component. But require all the other child components and put them in that object.

Comment: So inside the child component 'SOWType.js' then create 3 x further child components and refer to them inside the 'componentList' object in 'SOWType.js'? (i.e. <firstExtendedComponent /> etc)

Comment: Just tried this again (not in props but below the map function) and it's now working, thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Great! I am glad it helped.

Comment: Hi, Could i please request further clarification, the object 'componentList' is sitting in the child component 'SOWType.js'.

How do i get the values from the components in 'componentList' into the parent component 'PdfGenFormContainer.js' so that they are available in state (and therefore available for form submission) ?

Comment: Why don't you move the componentList in the parent component 'PdfGenFormContainer.js' and pass it on to child component 'SOWTypes.js' through props. So this way you can access it using this.props.componentList in SOWTypes.js

Comment: Thanks for your response, i'm still quite new at this so i'm not sure how to set it all up properly, do i have to put 'componentList' in state? 'componentList' is an object containing components (that will need their own props for the selection options they will contain i.e.  'ProdSOWExtOptions.js' in the ExtendedOptions folder is going to have drop-down boxes)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/1350o4277q

Check this out. I just edited your sandbox. See if it makes sense to you what I did. Moved ComponentList to parent component and passed it down to component through <SOWType/> and now SOWTypes.js uses ComponentList through props like so ```this.props.ComponentList```

Comment: Hey, that's great, thank-you, i see what you did, i didn't know you could put objects in the top of the component like that. As per this edited sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/9l7y820mly i have now tried to give the first extended component it's own properties as it contains a textbox which needs to be included in the final form submission. I have done this as per lines 32 and 201 in 'PDFGenFormContainer'. I think the onChange function is coming through ok but the value is saying undefined - have i set this up correctly? How do i put these props in SOWType.js so ProdSOWExtOptions can see them

Comment: Okay finally caught the reason. You seem to have used wrong name for onChange function while passing it on to child component. So onChange was the problem and that's why it was undefined.
https://codesandbox.io/s/vmpzm0xr70

Comment: I've just realised that I omitted 'prodSowTestInformation' from state. The solution in https://codesandbox.io/s/vmpzm0xr70 works but it is not updating anything in state? This sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/730z3295w0) shows prodSOW and Custom Prof Services with textboxes that will 'work' as long as lines 26 and 27 (in PDFGenFormContainer) are greyed out? How would state get incorporated in this scenario and is the 'value' prop required (as per customer information component in line 210) because using it twice (lines 230 and 233) causes a problem with using the same prop name twice?